# How to access doctrine database made by php from python

Tags: php, python, symfony, frameworks

I have web application which made by symfony2(php framework)

So there is mysql database handled by doctrine2 php source code.

Now I want to control this DB from python script.

Of course I can access directly to DB from python.

However, it is complex and might break the doctrine2 rule.

Is there a good way to access database via php doctrine from python??

Comment: "However, it is complex and might break the doctrine2 rule." => if you only want to query the DB and not change anything in the schema, doctrine2 rules will not be broken. You should look into peewee library. It's a super easy python ORM.

Comment: Add a REST (or whatever) api over your app, and make your python code a client of this API.

Comment: I see make api sounds like also the good way

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Django ORM or SQL Alchemy but the configuration of the models have to be done very carefully. Maybe you can write a parser from Doctrine2 config files to Django models. If you do, open source it please.

Comment: I see,,,,, i need to write the same model in Django ORM or SQL Alchemy as symfony ORM. Parser might be the best answer. I will check.